# Allow to post link to question, answer, proposals etc with description?

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks, onebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow me to marry text to a onebox in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120285/allow-me-to-marry-text-to-a-onebox-in-chat)

In chat, I can post a link to chat message/question/answer/proposal (area51) etc.

However, I can't add anything but that link into my message if I want it to onebox.

I have to post 2 messages to do something like

> Hey jeremy, this one is good
>   //wait 1 second
>   http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/715745#715745

I would like to do something like

> Hey jeremy, this one is good: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/715745#715745

But if I try this, it isn't transferred to a detailed link as [this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/715744#715744).

Could this be allowed?

**edit** it happened just now [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/715751#715751)

Comment: Basically the same as this proposal but with more momentum: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120285/154510

Answer (score 4):

I would like this feature as well, but on the other hand I don't want *every* link to onebox.  I propose something like the following:

### Gets oneboxed

Link by itself (current behavior)

> `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105687/154510`

Inline link with some sort of markup, e.g. prefixed with `!` (**new behavior**)

> `Check this out: !http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105687/154510`

This was actually how I thought it worked when I first started using chat.  I think it makes sense to use the `!` similar to posting an image in a question/answer, since you're creating an emphasized visual element.

### Doesn't get oneboxed

Inline link with no markup (current behavior)

> `Check this out:` `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105687/154510`

Comment: yes, good idea. I'm with you