# Allow me to marry text to a onebox in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Currently, oneboxing requires that the URL be the only thing in a chat message.  If additional text is added with the url in the same chat message, oneboxing won't work.

If other people are chatting, they can break in and divorce the onebox from the descriptive text:

[image]

Please fix chat in some way so that the descriptive text can stay with the onebox, without messages from other chat users breaking in:

[image]

Comment: This happens to me every day but I've never seen it as a problem. Would love to see it implemented though.

Comment: "Parent" post: [this answer by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120284/131713) to a similar chat functionality change request

Comment: Jeff *did* ask for it.

Comment: Damn that also happens to me often. +1

Comment: Somewhat related: [The chat anti spam measures are annoying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106964/154510) and [The purpose of chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/174930#174930)

Comment: I am both happy and angry.  I'm hangry.

Comment: @won at least this request makes sense

Comment: This might not be legalized in some states yet.

Comment: @Won't, you joke, but "a hangry kid is one who steps off the bus ravenous, irritable..." -[_For Kids With ADHD, Some Foods May Complement Treatment_](http://www.wbur.org/npr/144796050/for-kids-with-adhd-the-elimination-diet-falls-short-of-success)

Comment: I see what you did there.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: ***Whaaaaaat??*** My version made total sense, and handled the two irksome quirks that I encounter in chat every time I join!

Answer (score 27):

Since this is presented better I've voted to close [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105687/154510) as a dupe of this.  I made a suggestion there that I'll reproduce below.

---

I would like this feature as well, but on the other hand I don't want *every* link to onebox.  I propose something like the following:

### Gets oneboxed

Link by itself (current behavior)

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120285/154510
```

Inline link with some sort of markup, e.g. prefixed with `!` (**new behavior**)

```
Check this out: !https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120285/154510
```

This was actually how I thought it worked when I first started using chat.  I think it makes sense to use the `!` similar to posting an image in a question/answer, since you're creating an emphasized visual element, but the syntax could be anything.

### Doesn't get oneboxed

Inline link with no markup (current behavior)

```
Check this out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120285/154510
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just put the link on its own line like it is now?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek You could, sure, but a lot of people don't put newlines in chat messages (used to Enter sending a message, not knowing about Shift-Enter, whatever).  I'm up for any syntax really though, as long as it's simple enough.

Comment: I think it would be easier on the logic if the url was either the first or last line of a multi-line message, it would still be oneboxed with the additional content still be part of the message.  Then of course, people will have to know about how to put in the multi-line messages which is less of an issue.

Comment: `!` is already used in chat for oneboxing images from URLs without image file extensions.

Comment: @mootinator Thaaaat explains my confusion before!  Thanks.